# Python: how can I transform an array in a matrix with N columns, that are the same array repeated N times?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, parameters

I have an array and I have to create a matrix with N columns (N is a parameter that can be changed). So we have to copy this array N times.

Comment: Could you add an example in your question? For instance: `a = [12, 8, 9]; n = 2`. And then add the desired output for it. Maybe `b = [[12, 12], [8, 8], [9, 9]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your input would be for example:

```
a = [12, 8, 9]
n = 2
```

And the output would be:

```
b = [[12, 12],
     [ 8,  8],
     [ 9,  9]]
```

Here is how you could do that:

```
b = [[i]*n for i in a]
```